# MongoDB aggregate function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to display a list of the last messages between User A and any other User. Here is what I have so far, but let me explain what wrong with the below query:

If User A messages 'Test1' to User B, and User B replies with 'Test2', and then User A replies with 'Test3', then only the Test2 message will show up.

The 'Test1' message will show up first, as it's the first message in the conversation, but from there on, it will only show User B's messages.

The behavior I want is for the query to always return 'Test3', in this case. Here is what I have:

My Model:

```
const MostRecentMessageSchema = new Schema({
  to: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  from: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user"
  },
  conversation: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "conversation"
  },
  deletedBy: {
    type: [String]
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

```
        await MostRecentMessages.aggregate(
          [
            {
              $match: {
                $or: [
                  { from: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) },
                  { to: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
                ],
                deletedBy: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) },
                _id: { $ne: filteredIds }
              }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 1, from: 1, to: 1, conversation: 1, date: 1 } },
            { $sort: { date: -1 } },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: {
                  userConcerned: {
                    $cond: {
                      if: {
                        $eq: ["$to", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)]
                      },
                      then: "$to",
                      else: "$from"
                    }
                  },
                  interlocutor: {
                    $cond: {
                      if: {
                        $eq: ["$to", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)]
                      },
                      then: "$from",
                      else: "$to"
                    }
                  }
                },
                from: { $first: "$from" },
                to: { $first: "$to" },
                date: { $first: "$date" },
                conversation: { $first: "$conversation" }
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "conversations",
                localField: "conversation",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "conversation"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$conversation" } },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "to",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "to"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$to" } },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "from",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "from"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: { path: "$from" } }
          ],
          function(err, mostRecentMessages) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error fetching most recent messages", err);
            } else {
              if (connectedUsersAllMessages[userId]) {
                allMessagesSocket.sockets.connected[
                  connectedUsersAllMessages[userId].socketId
                ].emit("response", {
                  mostRecentMessages
                });
              }
            }
          }
        );
      }, 5000);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Here is a [POC](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zj16JaPmlEQ). It should return

```
  {
    from: "A",
    to: "C",
    number: 3,
    message: "A-C Test 4"
  },
```

but it returns,

```
  {
    from: "C",
    to: "A",
    number: 3,
    message: "A-C Test 3"
  },
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest including a *small* sample of data and an expected result which can actually be obtained from that data. Note that "schema" really does not matter here. Nothing in an `aggregate()` statement pays any attention to schema anyway. Also take note that you are asking to use `$lookup` here, so obviously there is another collection with related documents involved. Give people enough data in order to reproduce the desired result themselves.

Comment: I've added a POC

Comment: Your POC doesn't seem to match the schema in your question.  In the configuration on the playground, there are no date/time fields, so you are sorting by the number field, but there are multiple messages with the same number, so the `$first` operator returns whichever messages happens to be first in the array.  If you give 'A-C test 4' the number 4, it will sort properly and give the desired result.